# executeFetchRequest doesn't return the NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: swift, xcode6

This is for XCode 6 and Swift...

I'm trying to make a fetch request to the managed object context but it's not returning the correct subclass.

I have already set the subclass in the data model data modeler configuration to the name of my custom subclass and in the code, it is extending the NSManagedObject class.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show us some code you tried and the error you get for us to help you!

Comment: It works for me if I use the "as" keyword: var tasks = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: err) as [Task]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just figured out the solution.

I had to add the `@objc` attribute to allow the class to be compatible with Objective-C.

Now the fetch request is returning a correct result of `Tasks[]`

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Task) // make compatible with objective-c
class Task : NSManagedObject
{
    @NSManaged var note: String!
    @NSManaged var completed: Bool
}
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_36

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! I had been missing this, and my code _seemed_ to work by subclassing NSManagedObject, but I wasn't ending up with instances of the real class.

Comment: Importantly, you need the explicit class name in parentheses, rather than just putting `@objc` which I believe is usually OK if you are not sending a different class name to Objective-C.

Comment: It works, but the funny part is: *When you define a Swift class that inherits from NSObject or any other Objective-C class, the class is automatically compatible with Objective-C.* That means it should work without it when subclassing `NSManagedObject`, but doesn't. Thanks for giving the hint.

Comment: @ViktorLexington I think that's a typo, I've just had the same problem and the class has to inherit from NSManagedObject. vutran, hope this edit is OK.

Answer (score 8):

Using `@objc(Task)` seems to be working but you could also just edit the data model data modeler configuration to the name `ToDoList.Task` instead of just `Task`. That will work too and avoid Class conflicts if `Task` is used anywhere else in the Objective-C code.

Comment: I don't understand it. Do you mean in the `xcdatamodeld` file the **configuration** tab? There I have a table for every entity. Should I change the name in the column `Entity` or `Class`?

Comment: You should replace the class field as `Project.Object` like `ToDoList.Task`. Swift generate unique classes and it won't find it if you use `Task` only.

Comment: Cool it worked, using the project name is comprehensible since Swift uses Namespaces. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that in the "Entity" inspector (right side of the screen, Utilities pane) when Task is selected in your Model that its Class field is properly filled in with "Task" (it's blank by default).

Comment: Just checked and the "Class" as set to "Task"...  

Name: Task  
Class: Task  
Abstract Entity: unchecked  
Parent Entity: No Parent Entity