# swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional issues in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I have the following `NSManagedObject` in swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var first_name: String
    @NSManaged public var last_name: String
}
```

I have a class which provides the value with a function below:

```
- (id)getUserAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    User *user = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return user;
}
```

When I call this function from an `Objective-C` class, everything works fine. I call like so:

```
User *user = [self.userAccessor getUserAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And i'm able to continue from there. When I call it from a `Swift` class like so:

```
let user: User = self.userAccessor.getUserAtIndexPath(indexPath) as User
```

I get the `swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional` every time. Is there anything i'm doing wrong? Why is the same function working in `Objective-C` and not `Swift`? I even put a break point and can confirm on the `Swift` call the return is a valid variable! Some how `Swift` is just missing it.

I tried reading the below on this:

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/understanding-the-fatal-error-cant-unwrap-optional-none-errors-in-swift/

[AnyObject array returned by NSFetchRequest errors with "Swift dynamic cast failed" upon cast in Swift XCode 6 Beta 4 in XCTestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099823/anyobject-array-returned-by-nsfetchrequest-errors-with-swift-dynamic-cast-faile)

Is there anything else i'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps the cast should be `User?` instead of `User`?

Comment: When I do that, i get `nil` when i do `println(user)` in swift.

Comment: That means your get method is having trouble.  You are not allowed to typecast nil without an error (it's actually one of the definitions I've seen of a proper `undefined` function).

Comment: I got the solution below. It's working fine on the `Objective-C` side--I see with breakpoints getting the values properly. It's just not passing to `Swift` for some reason.

Comment: I had to add the `@objc(User)` as per below.

Comment: A lot of Core Data, KVO, anything that requires introspection, etc. will break if Swift stuff isn't marked @objc or dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution here:

[Swift: Breakpoint in CoreData library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841856/swift-breakpoint-in-coredata-library)

Basically I had to put `@objc(User)` right above managed object code. So as per below:

```
@objc(User)
public class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var first_name: String
    @NSManaged public var last_name: String
}
```

This solved the problem. Case closed.