# Really stumped - Swift Dynamic Cast Failed when trying to move data between ViewControllers

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

This seems like it should be so simple - I have researched and looked and tried different things and just can't figure it out.  I have a view controller which allows a user to enter their own review of a winery.  Its a modal view from a detail winery page - I am simply trying to populate a Label in this modal view with the winery name from the previous view. (then saving the winery name and the users review) the review part worked fine - its transferring the name over that is giving me fits crashing on me with "Swift Dynamic Cast Failed" Any help is greatly appreciated see code:

"review" view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyReviewViewController: UIViewController {

var myreview:wineryReview!
var passName:String!


@IBOutlet weak var wineryNameLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myReview:UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    wineryNameLabel.text = passName
```

**the code of the passing tableviewcontroller:**

```
var wineryNames = "Glenora Wine Cellars"
(because I am just testing functionaility the variable is just simply called)         in the class

// MARK: - Navigation


 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "mapWinery" {
        let mvc = segue.destinationViewController as WineryMapViewController
        mvc.wineryMap = wineryAddress
    }
    if segue.identifier == "goToMyReview" {
        let mrvc = segue.destinationViewController as MyReviewViewController
        mrvc.passName = wineryNames
    }

}
```

Error:

`libswiftCore.dylib swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x103450860:  pushq  %rbp
0x103450861:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x103450864:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x103450867:  je     0x10345089e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x103450869:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x103450873:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x103450876:  jne    0x10345089e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x103450878:  leaq   0xb52e9(%rip), %rax
0x10345087f:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x103450882:  andq   (%rdi), %rax
0x103450885:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x103450890:  cmpq   %rsi, %rax
0x103450893:  je     0x1034508ad               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
0x103450895:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x103450899:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x10345089c:  jne    0x103450890               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x10345089e:  leaq   0x36b7d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x1034508a5:  movq   %rax, 0xb4c0c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x1034508ac:  int3

0x1034508ad:  movq   %rdi, %rax
0x1034508b0:  popq   %rbp
0x1034508b1:  retq

0x1034508b2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)`

Comment: When is this occurring? Should save be executing or just viewdidload?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307335/swift-dynamiccastclassunconditional-issues-in-swift

Comment: just view did load - it crashes when the button is pressed which takes you to this view controller - save only executes upon a save button press in this view

Comment: @MikeGibbs Do you have something in prepareforsegue in the previous view controller that sets passName? That's more relevant than the save function you've included but doesn't get a chance to run.

Comment: yes as follows: 'override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "mapWinery" {
            let mvc = segue.destinationViewController as WineryMapViewController
            mvc.wineryMap = wineryAddress
        }
        if segue.identifier == "goToMyReview" {
            let mrvc = segue.destinationViewController as MyReviewViewController
            mrvc.passName = wineryNames
        }'

    }

Comment: I know this should work as you can see I have to prepareforsegues and the first one works fine when I pass it to a different view controller

Comment: Are you sure `wineryNames` is a `String`? Where does that get set? Edit the original post if you can.

Comment: Use debugger, otherwise this like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: `passName` and `myreview` should be optionals (? not !), they don't exist when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @Nick - I changed prepareforsegue - anyobject? with a question mark and in the destination view controller my var passName:String? with a question mark - still no luck - my review stays with an exclamation point as it refers to my entity class.

Comment: @Sulthan what am I looking for in the debugger?  I am still learning and not really clear what I am looking at when I go through the debugger