# Subclassing conversion error in parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I get an error while trying to cast a result from a PFQuery into the correct Subclass.

The error is `swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional`

My code looks something like this:

```
let resellerQuery = Reseller.query()    // Reseller is a subclass of PFObject

resellerQuery.fromLocalDatastore()

resellerQuery.whereKey("name", equalTo: resellerName)

resellerQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result: PFObject?, error) -> Void in

   if (error == nil) {
      let resellerObject = result as Reseller
   }
})
```

I get the error on the line where I create the resellerObject.

```
let resellerObject = result as Reseller
```

Do you have any ide what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a runtime error or compile error? This post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307335/swift-dynamiccastclassunconditional-issues-in-swift

Comment: Did you do "4. Call [YourClass registerSubclass] before Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:. An easy way to do this is with your class' +load method in Objective-C or with +initialize in Swift."?

Comment: I have the `registerSubclass()` method in my initialize() method.

`override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }`